# PostgreSql desbordamiento numérico

Tags: postgresql

Estoy intentando insertar un registro, pero cuando voy a guardarlo, me sale un error

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: desbordamiento de campo numeric
  Detail: Un campo con precisión 10, escala 10 debe redondear a un valor absoluto menor que 1.
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2455)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2155)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:288)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:430)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:356)
```

El único campo que tengo que sea escala 10 es ->

```
PRICE DECIMAL (10,10)
```

Y el valor que intento insertar es ->

```
Double -> 7.0
```

Los otros campos son ->

- `DECIMAL (20,5)`

Pero no sé porque me da error... Gracias

Comment: Pureba poniendolo de tipo numeric, donde la escala sera el numero maximo de digitos a aceptar y la precision en numero de decimales, por ejemplo price(10,3) aceptara un numero de 10 digitos incluyendo el punto y solo permite 3 decimales

Comment: Porque intentas ingresar el valor de tipo double en un campo tipo decimal?

Comment: Porque el pojo tiene servir para modelo de datos relaciones y para los no-relaciones, ya tuve lío con el tipo INTEGER con ambos, el double no da problemas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al parecer tienes un problema por la parametrizacion del tipo de dato decimal, en postgres la configuracion de este tipo de dato consta de una parte entera (digitos) y la parte decimal (precisión)

Ej: DECIMAL(5,2), de los 5 digitos 3 para la parte entera y hasta 2 para la parte decimal 000.00

En el campo "PRICE" estas configurando diez digitos con precision de diez digitos, puedes ingresar numeros que empizen con cero (0.123456).Si se supera la parte entera aparece un error de desbordamiento, si supera la parte decimal se omiten los digitos restantes.

Mas información
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-numeric.html